# NonlinearModelFit doesn't seem to work with inverse function - please help!

Tags: fitting

I have the following defined:

```
lvf1 = Table[{i, 1/(10 - i)}, {i, -100, 100}];
```

If I just run this, it gives me a "Power: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered." error,  so I added this to remove that point from the dataset:

```
lvf1 = Delete[lvf1, 111];
```

It looks like this:

```
ListPlot[lvf1]
```

[image]

Now, when I run this:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[lvf1, a/(b - x) + c, {a, b, c}, x];
```

I get all kinds of errors:

[image]

Why!? I've used the NonlinearModelFit function like this elsewhere, and it typically works. I can't seem to get it to work with any reciprocal/inverse type function. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Provide a non-integral initial point:

```
NonlinearModelFit[lvf1, a/(b - x) + c, {a, {b, π^2}, c}, x]
```

Comment: A non-integral initial point for `b` does remove the error messages but the initial value of $\pi$ doesn't result in an appropriate fit.  If  `{a, {b, 9.1}, c}` is used, then an appropriate fit is found.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need initial points when using `Method->"NMinimize"`

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[lvf1, a/(b - x) + c, {a, b, c}, x,Method -> "NMinimize"];
Normal[nlm] (*  -8.88269*10^-9 + 1./(10. - x)  as expected*)

Show[{Plot[Normal[nlm], {x, -100, 100}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.02]],ListPlot[lvf1, PlotStyle -> Red]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that using `Method -> "NMinimize"` starts out with either better automatic initial points or that using that method is less sensitive in this case to the automatic initial points (which I thought was 1 for all parameters)?  It's still an iterative method so there must be initial points.

Comment: @  JimB I don't know which initial points NMinimize uses, often the method is more robust than the default methods.

Comment: Thanks.  I see now.  That method is more robust which means that it is much less often that one needs to supply customized initial values.